# Union variables from separate files in C

Tags: c, embedded, unions

Is it possible to union a variable declared `extern` in another file? This is for an embedded application where memory needs to be preserved, so sharing as much as possible.
ie:

file1.h:

```
extern char Buffer1[ 10 ];
```

file2.h

```
extern char Buffer2[ 15 ];
```

?????

```
typedef union
{
  Buffer1; 
  Buffer2;
} uBuffers;
```

I realize this is not the correct syntax without the type, but if the type is used then a new variable is declared. They could be explicitly placed in RAM but that removes flexibility.

Edit:
Thanks for the answers.
What I should have made clear is the reason this situation has arisen.
I have had to include some optimised assembler that uses the variables I was hoping to union together. However the assembler syntax does not allow unions ie EXTERN uBuffers.Buffer1 - generates a syntax error.

Comment: Why do you want to access what would essentially be the same buffer via two different names?  Why not define one global buffer and reference it by the same name everywhere you use it?

Answer (score 3):

The `extern` declarations simply tell the compiler that these variables exist somewhere, and what their types are.  When you reference those symbols, the compiler will leave a hole in the code where the linker can plug in the actual addresses once they are known.  You will need to arrange for the linker to assign the same address to both symbols.  You could declare a global variable called `Buffer1and2` of the union type, and then use some inline asm to `equ`ate `Buffer1` and `Buffer2` to `Buffer1and2`.  The `equ` should create new symbols in the symbol table with the same value (address).

Note that this does not work for non-static or uninitialized data which is placed in the `.comm` section.  This is a pretty ugly hack, but it does cause two separate global variables to appear at the same address without them appearing to be union members...

dut.h

```
typedef char Buffer1[25];
typedef char Buffer2[30];

extern Buffer1 buffer1;
extern Buffer2 buffer2;
```

dut.c

```
#include "dut.h"

static union {
    Buffer1 buffer1;
    Buffer2 buffer2;
} bufferX;

__asm(".globl  buffer1\n"
      ".equ    buffer1, bufferX\n"
      ".globl  buffer2\n"
      ".equ    buffer2, bufferX\n");
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dut.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    buffer1[0] = 0xa5;
    printf("%02x\n", buffer2[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this should be a last resort, if you cannot modify the code that refers to `buffer1` and `buffer2`.  If you can modify the code, then you should just extern a union, and have the code refer to one of the members of the union, as described in @Dmitri's answer.

Comment: +1 That is very clever. It opens up an entire world of (often incredibly devious and dangerous) possibilities. I hope I don't have to use it, but it's a great trick to know just in case.

Answer (score 1):

A good way of organizing this is to have a common_buffer.h that defines the struct and includes the extern declaration (don't forget the include guards):

```
typedef union {
    uint16_t buf1[BUF1_SIZE];
    uint8_t  buf2[BUF2_SIZE];
} uBuffers_type;

extern uBuffers_type ubuffers_var;
```

you can either include the actual allocation for it in an existing compilation unit (.c file) or create a separate common_buffer.c which contains

```
#include "common_buffer.h"
uBuffers_type ubuffers_var;
```

Be sure that the non-extern variable declaration appears once and only once in your entire project. From there on, any file where you

```
#include "common_buffer.h"
```

will be able to use the buffers with something like

```
ubuffers_var.buf1[index] = someUInt16;
```

or

```
someUInt8 = ubuffers_var.buf2[other_index];
```

Comment: Obviously, doing stuff like this comes with certain risks. Be sure you know what you are doing when it comes to concurrency and management of your program's complexity and maintainability. In embedded systems you sometimes have to break the high-level software design rules, but be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest  declare the union in one file,

a common header file needs an 'extern' for that union and the union definition.

Each file that uses that union needs to include the common header.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be misunderstanding something here.

The code `extern char Buffer1[ 10 ];` says that an object is declared in another file.  That is, ten `char`s' worth of space has been allocated and given the name `Buffer1`.

The code `typedef union {  Buffer1;  Buffer2; } uBuffers;` only defines a data type called `uBuffers`.  No storage has been allocated, and no object exists until you declare one.

You can't use a union to take two already-existing objects and tell the compiler that they should share the same memory space.  You have to *replace* the existing objects with a union.  For example, use something like this in a header visible to both source files:

```
// create union data type
union my_union
{
    char Buffer1[10];
    char Buffer2[15];
};

// the real declaration needs to be added to a source file somewhere
extern union my_union buffers;
```

In your particular case, both objects are char arrays so the easier solution is to just have a single buffer like `char buffer[15];`.  The union method is generally more useful when different members have drastically different data types.